# EclipseLink error 50035 when using XmlIDREF/XmlID with interfaces and generalization

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am trying out the  `@XmlIDREF` reference approach. The annotation is:

```java
 /**
   * getter for Attribute/List<Attribute> attributes
   * @return attributes
   */
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="attributes")
  @XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="Attribute", type=AttributeJaxbDao.class)
  })
  @XmlIDREF
  public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
```

which leads to the error message:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: Since the property or field [attributes] is set as XmlIDREF, the target type of each XmlElement declared within the XmlElements list must have an XmlID property.  Please ensure the target type of XmlElement [Attribute] contains an XmlID property.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50035] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: Since the property or field [attributes] is set as XmlIDREF, the target type of each XmlElement declared within the XmlElements list must have an XmlID property.  Please ensure the target type of XmlElement [Attribute] contains an XmlID property.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:143)
```

although `AttributeJaxbDao` has the annotation:

```java
 /**
   * getter for xsd:string/String id
   * @return id
   */
  @XmlAttribute(name="id")  
  @XmlID
  public String getId() {
```

There are two differences to the "standard use" `@XmlIDREF`/`@XmlID`:

1. AttributeJaxbDao is a derived class - the annotation is in the superclass
2. Attribute is an Interface - the type has specifically been named to be AttributeJaxbDao.class in the `@XmlElement` annotation

How come the error shows up in this situation?
Would there be a work around for this. I'd like to avoid to be forced to not use the interface and the generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

There were unfortunately 2 bugs that we preventing this use case from working correctly.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/401074
- http://bugs.eclipse.org/401294

These bugs have been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5.0 streams.  These streams are currently in development, a nightly build can be downloaded from the following link (starting Feb 22, 2013):

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

**FULL EXAMPLE**

Below is a slightly more complicated model than the one given in your question that I'm going to use to demonstrate that everything now works correctly.

***Foo***

The `Foo` class has two properties of type `List<Attribute>`, `Attribute` is an interface.  Both are annotated with `@XmlElements` which contain `@XmlElement` annotations that specify the concrete types.  The `attributeRefs` property is also annotated with `@XmlIDREF`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Attributes")
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="AttributeFoo", type=AttributeJaxbDao.class),
        @XmlElement(name="AttributeBar", type=AttributeJaxbDao2.class)
      })
    List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();;


    @XmlElementWrapper(name="AttributeRefs")
    @XmlElements({
      @XmlElement(name="AttributeRefFoo", type=AttributeJaxbDao.class),
      @XmlElement(name="AttributeRefBar", type=AttributeJaxbDao2.class)
    })
    @XmlIDREF
    List<Attribute> attributeRefs = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

}
```

***Attribute***

`Attribute` is just a very simple interface.

```java
public interface Attribute {

}
```

***AttributeJaxbDao***

This is an implementation of `Attribute` that contains a field annotated with `@XmlID` that will be leveraged by the `@XmlIDREF` annotation.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AttributeJaxbDao implements Attribute {

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")  
    @XmlID
    String id;

    String name;

}
```

***AttributeJaxbDao2***

This is also an implementation of `Attribute` that has a field annotated with `@XmlID`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AttributeJaxbDao2 implements Attribute {

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")  
    @XmlID
    String id;

    String name;

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code that you can run to prove that everything works:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14921547/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

***input.xml/Output***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <Attributes>
        <AttributeFoo id="a">
            <name>A</name>
        </AttributeFoo>
        <AttributeBar id="b">
            <name>B</name>
        </AttributeBar>
        <AttributeFoo id="c">
            <name>C</name>
        </AttributeFoo>
    </Attributes>
    <AttributeRefs>
        <AttributeRefFoo>a</AttributeRefFoo>
        <AttributeRefBar>b</AttributeRefBar>
        <AttributeRefFoo>c</AttributeRefFoo>
    </AttributeRefs>
</foo>
```

Comment: As a workaround you can make the property of the impl type.  Also, we should be able to get a fix checked in tomorrow that be available in the 2.4.2 nightly build on Wednesday morning.

Comment: Blaise - I can't List<interface> is incompatible to List<impltype> in Java ... please read my personal message regarding the combination of features i am looking for: generics, interfaces, inheritance, ref/id handling

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and all the effort. The problem simply persists: Exception Description: Since the property or field [attributes] is set as XmlIDREF, the target type of each XmlElement declared within the XmlElements list must have an XmlID property.  Please ensure the target type of XmlElement [Attribute] contains an XmlID property.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50035] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130315-93567e3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException

I assume it's because the inheritance in your example is the other way round.

Comment: I had to comment out this:
// @XmlSeeAlso({AttributeJaxbDao.class})
in the base class of AttributeJaxbDao ... very strange

Comment: @WolfgangFahl - Could you open a bug for the issue you are seeing (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink)?  If you could attach sample code to it that demonstrates the issue that will help us put together a fix faster.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response. The bug report is in the works. I have created a JUnit test showing the issue.